# Which one is grammatically correct and why

Tags: grammar, questions

When did you quit smoking?
Or
When have you quit smoking?

Answer (score 1):

Neither is incorrect, but the first one is much more usual when asking when a past event happened.

You might use the second when talking about events in a person's whole life.

*"I have tried several times to quit smoking."*

*"When have you [ever] tried to quit smoking?"*