# What is the correct answer and why?

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-structure, sequence-of-tenses

When you (quit) smoking?
I (not/smoke) for over five years now,and I will never smoke again.

Comment: What do you think Amira? We ask questioners to do a little homework themselves first.

Comment: That didn't answer my question and I am confused is it "when did you quit smoking?  Or when have you quit smoking ? "

Comment: Which would you choose?  And what tense would you use for the second part?

Comment: I have already answered that at https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/268606/which-one-is-grammatically-correct-and-why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the first question, you need a helping verb to complete the tense. "When will you quit smoking?" or "When did you quit smoking?" There are cases when we don't know whether an event is past or future, but English has no verb tense to convey that Idea.

Similarly, your second sentence should use the past tense as you go on to say it was 5 years ago. "I quit smoking over five years ago." Or you could use a present perfect: "I have not smoked for over five years."